# UITableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath fails to change image in cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a programatically created table view that loads a cell from a nib

In cellForRowAtIndexPath, I manage cell UIImageView’s like this:

```
UIImageView *rowImageView = (UIImageView*) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:49];
[rowImageView [self imageForRow:row selected:NO]];
```

The normal image is displayed properly in the cell.

In order to change the cell image when selected, I use this method:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    UITableViewCell* cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *rowImageView = (UIImageView*) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:49];
    [rowImageView setImage:[self imageForRow:row selected:YES]];

    // test
    // the view controller background is successfully changed to the selected image
    self.backgroundImageView.image = [self imageForRow:row selected:YES];
    // the row image view is not nil
    if( rowImageView == nil ) NSLog(@"nil");

    return indexPath;
}
```

I also ensured the table view allows selection, and tested selection by not setting the initial image view, tapping the cell and watching the default background color change to blue.  So I know the selection is occurring, but for some reason the image isn’t changing.

Comment: Have you tried changing the image in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` instead of `willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems:

1) In your `willSelectRow...` method, change:

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

to:

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

The way you are doing it you end up creating a new cell and updating its image. But that's not the cell that is being displayed.

2) In your `cellForRow...` method, you need to keep track of whether the cell should show the selected or unselected image and setup the cell with the proper image.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem and used some thing like this in initWithCoder in MyCustomCell:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
  if (self  = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
    UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.frame];
    bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:22.0 / 255.0 green:163.0 / 255.0 blue:171.0 / 255.0 alpha:1];
    self.selectedBackgroundView = bgView;
 }

  return self;
}
```

Gave it a try, it may help you